# Saving data from table of COVID-19 infections in Germany

Tags: java, parsing, covid-19, jsoup

I wrote a program that saves the data from the first table of [this](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19-Pandemie_in_Deutschland) Wikipedia article (in German) and then saves the column "Gesamt" (contains daily update of absolute numbers of COVID-19 infected people in Germany) together with the date in a CSV file. After that it draws a chart with logarithmical axis.

For the parsing, I used JSoup and for saving the data in the CSV file, I used a `FileWriter`. For the chart, I used swing and JFree.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jfree.chart.axis.LogAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import javax.swing.*;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

public class Corona {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int[] array = getData();
        saveData(array);
        visualizeData(array);
    }

    public static int[] getData() {

        //Saving data from wikipedia in a 2D-String-Array

        String url = "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19-Pandemie_in_Deutschland";
        String[][] a = new String[365][30];
        try{
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Element table = doc.getElementsByClass("wikitable zebra toptextcells mw-collapsible").first();
            Elements rows = table.getElementsByTag("tr");

            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            for (Element row : rows) {
                Elements cells = row.getElementsByTag("td");
                for (Element cell : cells) {
                    a[j][i] = cell.text().concat(", ");
                    i++;
                }
                j++;
                i = 0;
            }

        }

        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Only taking column with absolute numbers for whole country

        int[] array = new int[365];
        for(int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
            if(a[k][17] != null) {
                a[k][17] = a[k][17].split(",")[0];
                a[k][17] = a[k][17].replaceAll("[.]","");
                array[k] = Integer.parseInt(a[k][17]);
            }

        }
        return array;
    }

    public static void saveData(int[] array) throws IOException {

        //Writing date and data from array to csv-file

        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 24);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("data.csv");
        writer.append("");
        writer.append("\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            writer.append(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")));
            writer.append(",");
            writer.append(Integer.toString(array[i + 1]));
            writer.append("\n");
            date = date.plusDays(1);
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }

    public static void visualizeData(int[] array) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //JFrame and JPanel

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Corona-Statistics");
                frame.setSize(600,600);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

                //Series gets filled up with data
                XYSeries series = new XYSeries("XYGraph");

                int i = 1;
                while(array[i] > 0) {
                    series.add(i - 1, array[i]);
                    i++;
                }

                //Printing the chart

                NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis("Days since 24-02-20");
                LogAxis yAxis = new LogAxis("People infected with Covid-19 in Germany");
                yAxis.setBase(10);
                XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(new XYSeriesCollection(series),
                        xAxis, yAxis, new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, false));
                JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(
                        "People infected with Covid-19 in Germany", JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, false);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                ChartPanel chartpanel = new ChartPanel(chart);

                //Adding chartpanel to panel

                panel.add(chartpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

                //Button to open csv

                JButton button = new JButton("Open csv");
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
                        try {
                            Process pp = run.exec("libreoffice data.csv");
                        }
                        catch(Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                //Button to update data

                JButton button2 = new JButton("Update data");
                button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                        try {
                            frame.setVisible(false);
                            frame.dispose();
                            final int[] a = getData();
                            saveData(a);
                            visualizeData(a);

                        }
                        catch(IOException e) {

                        }
                    }
                });

                //Adding buttons to subpanel

                JPanel subpanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
                subpanel.add(button);
                subpanel.add(button2);

                panel.add(subpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.add(panel);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

The program has no special purpose, it's for practice only.

My question now is: How can I improve the code?

Comment: Oh my, that's a lot of magic numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some suggestions for your code:

> ```
> String[][] a = new String[365][30];
> int i = 0;
> int j = 0;
> for (Element row : rows) {
>     Elements cells = row.getElementsByTag("td");
>     for (Element cell : cells) {
>         a[j][i] = cell.text().concat(", ");
>         i++;
>     }
>     j++;
>     i = 0;
> }
> ```

You are storing a m * n matrix of values retrieved by jsoup in a 2d array, but this can be avoided? Here the second part of your code :

> ```
> int[] array = new int[365];
> for(int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
>     if(a[k][17] != null) {
>         a[k][17] = a[k][17].split(",")[0];
>         a[k][17] = a[k][17].replaceAll("[.]","");
>         array[k] = Integer.parseInt(a[k][17]);
>     }
> }
> ```

The values you are interested are in the 17th column of the table, so instead of a 2d matrix, you can use directly an int array where to store elements. You are doing a lot of not necessary work parsing by yourself strings like "1.234" and convert them to integer without the point for thousands, use instead the class [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html):

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
int value = nf.parse("1.234").intValue(); // it will contain the number 1234
```

You can extract the 17th column values from your table using the jsoup `Element` `get` method checking if the row you are examining has at least 18 elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); ++i) {
    Elements cells = rows.get(i).getElementsByTag("td");
    if (cells.size() > 17) {
        Element cell = cells.get(17);
        array[i] = nf.parse(cell.text()).intValue(); //<-- nf.parse call
    }
}
```

So your method `getData` can be rewritten like this:

```
public static int[] getData() throws IOException, ParseException {
    String url = "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19-Pandemie_in_Deutschland";
    int[] array = new int[365];

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Element table = doc.getElementsByClass("wikitable zebra toptextcells mw-collapsible").first();
    Elements rows = table.getElementsByTag("tr");

    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); ++i) {
        Elements cells = rows.get(i).getElementsByTag("td");
        if (cells.size() > 17) {
            Element cell = cells.get(17);
            array[i] = nf.parse(cell.text()).intValue();
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

Some minor changes can be applied to your other method `saveData`, first is use of try with resources to avoid manual closing and flushing of the `FileWriter`:

```
try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("data.csv")) { /*here your logic*/ }
```

Second, to avoid use of consecutive appends , you can use the `write` method of the `FileWriter` class rewriting the method in this way:

```
public static void saveData(int[] array) throws IOException {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 24);
    DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("data.csv")) {
        writer.write("\n");
        String template = "%s,%d\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            String data = String.format(template, date.format(df), array[i + 1]);
            writer.write(data);
            date = date.plusDays(1);
        }
    }
}
```

I defined a `template` variable so the format of the data is more readable and easier to modify.